# Component - getting data from parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am learning Vue.js and I couldn't figure out why  `<li>{{task.body}}</li>` is not showing on the screen.

I have created `<tasks v-for="task in tasks"></tasks>` component and it need to access data from parents.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/pd03t1vm/

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <tasks v-for="task in tasks"></tasks>
</div>

<template id="tasks-template">
    <ul>
      <li>{{task.body}}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

JS:

```
Vue.component('tasks', {
    template: '#tasks-template',
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        tasks: [
            {body: 'Task 1 Something', completed: false},
            {body: 'Task 2 Something', completed: true},
            {body: 'Task 3 Something', completed: false},
            {body: 'Task 4 Something', completed: false}
        ]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are instantiating `<tasks>` components from the data in the root component, but you are not passing the current task into the `<tasks>` component, so it cannot access it at all.

[The Vue.js guide explains how to pass the data into a component using props](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props):

First you need to bind the current `tasks` to the prop (here I called it `item`) of the `<task>` component

```
<div id="app">
  <tasks v-for="task in tasks" :item="task"></tasks>
</div>
```

**Note that you bind the actual object using a `:` in front of the property name.**

Now you need to define the `item` property in the `<tasks>` component:

```
Vue.component('tasks', {
  props: ['item'],
  template: '#tasks-template',
});
```

By the way: Your code creates four instances of the `<tasks>` component, just in case you were wondering - this might not be what you expected your code to do exactly.